# Thumb scroll with large letter preview

Tags: android, fastscroll

I'm using a ListView object with thumb scrolling enabled and am wondering how to include a large letter preview, as can be seen in the image below:

[image]

I know how to make the thumb scroll work; it's the large letter preview I'm looking for.

n.b. to get thumb scrolling to work, I added the following line to my ListView object in the layout XML:

```
android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the SectionIndexer interface. Example @ http://spinettaro.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/android-snippet-code-android-listview.html

Comment: Hey, thanks for the link. This is similar, but not quite the same as above. Still could be useful though...

Comment: In fact, it is exactly the same. It just looks different depending on the SDK used.